# Filtering based on comparisons in django

Tags: django, date, comparison, field

I have a django model with a field `Reminder_End_Date = models.DateField()`.
I have to filter all records of the model which have reminder date greater than todays date.

However when I try to use the following statement, it does not work:

```
now=datetime.date.today()
reminderlist=Reminder.objects.filter(Reminder_End_Date>now )
```

Can anyone tell how to go about this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Changed the title because this is not an issue with datefields.

Answer (score 8):

This is basic Django query syntax. See [the documentation on making queries](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups-intro).

```
reminderlist = Reminder.objects.filter(Reminder_End_Date__gt=now )
```